# --node-args in PM2 while using json config mode

Tags: json, node.js, pm2

I have a question, that's how to pass "--node-args" arguments in PM2 while using json config mode, like this:

> pm2 start --node-args="--debug=5858" myPm2Config.json

well, **I know I can write the arguments into myPm2Config.json file, but I dont want to do this**, because I want to make two startup command as "debug" and "production"  mode for launch application, such as "pm2_run" and "pm2_debug", and "pm2_debug" command with --node-args argument and "pm2_run" not, and I dont want to make two "myPm2Config.json" files, because that means if something needs changed, I will need to change two json config files, so, is there any easy way to do it? thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution! that's use js config instead of json config.

first, I create a pm2.config.js file. (**mark: file name must be end with .config.js**）

```
//[pm2.config.js]

let config = {
  apps : [{
    name        : "node_shells",
    script      : "./bin/www",
    log_date_format  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS",
    log_file   : "logs/pm2.log",
    error_file : "logs/pm2-err.log",
    out_file   : "logs/pm2-out.log",
    pid_file   : "logs/pm2.pid",
    watch      :  true,
    ignore_watch : ["logs/*", "node_modules/*", "uploads/*"]
  }]
}

let debug_mode = false;
for(let arg of process.argv) {
  if(arg == '-debug') {
    debug_mode = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(debug_mode) {
  console.log('== launching in debug mode ==');
  config.apps[0].node_args = "--debug=5858";
}
else {
  console.log('== launching in production mode ==');
  config.apps[0].node_args = " ";   //*require! or it will always uses latest debug options
}

module.exports = config;
```

then, create two launch files: "pm2_run" and "pm2_debug".

```
#[pm2_run]
pm2 start pm2.config.js
```

---

```
#[pm2_debug]
pm2 start pm2.config.js -- -debug
```

now, it's easy to switch debug mode or production mode!